# SQL statement to select with group and count in a self reference table

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a table `members` as below:

| id | level | name | managedBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Erik |  |
| 2 | B | Jerald | 1 |
| 3 | C | Alexis | 2 |
| 4 | A | Johnathan |  |
| 5 | C | Doreen | 2 |
| 6 | B | Jay | 4 |
| 7 | C | Robin | 6 |
| 8 | C | Victor | 6 |
| 9 | C | Ethel | 6 |

Level A has the highest power. People at level A are not managed by anyone and they have the right to manage people at level B.
People at level B manage people at level C.

How to write a SQL statement that allows to count how many level C people each person at level A has, and sort this set from most to few?

Output:

| Name | memberCount |
| --- | --- |
| Johnathan | 3 |
| Erik | 2 |

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: what have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using self join as follows :

```
select A.name, count(C.managedby) as memberCount
from mytable A
inner join mytable B on A.id = B.managedBy
inner join mytable C on B.id = C.managedBy
group by A.name
```

Result :

| name | membercount |
| --- | --- |
| Johnathan | 3 |
| Erik | 2 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/KJIOfwat)

Comment: you're rock! it works like a charm!